# How do you install the VirtIO HDD drivers for KVM on Windows 7?

Tags: drivers, windows-7, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install Windows 7 64-bit on KVM. I created a VirtIO HDD in `virt-manager`, and connected the driver ISO from [here](https://launchpad.net/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/+download). The only drivers I see for storage are for Windows Server 2008, and 2008 R2. I tried the 2K8 folder. It found the driver, `Red Hat VirtIO SCSI controller, packaged by Canonical, Ltd` but could not find the disk.

> No new devices could be found. Make sure the driver files are correct
>   and located on the driver installation media.

[image: Screenshot of KVM HDD configuration]

[image: Screenshot of selecting a driver in the Windows 7 installer]

[image: Screenshot of Windows 7 installer error]

How do I get the Windows 7 installer to find my drive?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the correct drivers for your OS or, as you've discovered, it won't work. The driver ISO that you're using is old. The current drivers are located at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers. They're signed by Red Hat so that they'll install on Windows without complaint.

You'll need the viostor driver.

[image]

Comment: used that and the very latest ISO from the site linked, still getting the error. This isn't helping. Currently using virtio-win-0.1.112.iso.

Comment: This is not unique to this case.  It's happening to me and many other people.

Also, it's not limited to new installations.  I'm trying to mount an existing image and the same problem occurs.  KVM and the 64bit virtio drivers somehow don't see eye-to-eye when it comes to Windows 7 and later.